# How to pass username and password in npm gulp maven deploy plugin

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, gulp, npm-publish

I am using below code to publish my artifact to maven.
I am able to access repository also I am able to publish artifacts from command line to maven repository.
even after providing correct details I am getting 401 error while publishing artifact.

plugin link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-maven-deploy

Below is code snippet.

```
pipe(maven.deploy({
        'groupId': 'com.test',
        'repositories': [{
          'id': 'test',
          'url': 'http://localhost/maven_repo',
          'user': 'adasd',
          'password': 'XXXXXX'
  }]
```